# Writing tests for preferences, keep getting `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` when accessing preferences

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, sharedpreferences, android-espresso

I am just starting to learn testing on Android and this is driving me crazy. The feature works fine but I cannot get my tests to run. I am trying to read a value from `SharedPreferences` and compare it to the content of a TextView. I am using Espresso on Android Studio 2.3.3.

This line `String player1Name = sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.KEYplayerOneDefaultNameSetting), context.getString(R.string.playerOne));` causes this `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f09004d` exception. This is essentially the same code that I use in my Fragments to access shared preferences.

I could not find anything referencing this same problem. I feel like I just have a simple configuration error but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Here is my entire test:

```
@Test
public void setsPlayerNamesFromSettings(){
    Context context = getInstrumentation().getContext();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String player1Name = sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.KEYplayerOneDefaultNameSetting), context.getString(R.string.playerOne));
    onView(withId(R.id.LpCalculatorTextPlayer1Name)).check(matches(withText(player1Name)));
    String player2Name = sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.KEYplayerTwoDefaultNameSetting), context.getString(R.string.playerTwo));
    onView(withId(R.id.LpCalculatorTextPlayer2Name)).check(matches(withText(player2Name)));
}
```

If it's any assistance, here's code from my Fragment that access SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        mLpCalculatorModel.setLpDefault(Integer.parseInt(preferences.getString(getString(R.string.KEYdefaultLpSetting), "8000")));
        mLpCalculatorModel.setPlayer1Name(preferences.getString(getString(R.string.KEYplayerOneDefaultNameSetting), getString(R.string.playerOne)));
        mLpCalculatorModel.setPlayer2Name(preferences.getString(getString(R.string.KEYplayerTwoDefaultNameSetting), getString(R.string.playerTwo)));
        mLpCalculatorModel.setAllowsNegativeLp(preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.KEYallowNegativeLp), false));
        tvPlayer1Lp.setText(Integer.toString(mLpCalculatorModel.getLpDefault()));
        tvPlayer2Lp.setText(Integer.toString(mLpCalculatorModel.getLpDefault()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
getInstrumentation().getContext()
```

This returns a `Context` representing your `androidTest` source set. If your resources are elsewhere (e.g., `main`), use:

```
getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! Such a simple mistake.